# Getting number of tables loaded with integrated mapping

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, ms-access

I am integrating a MapInfo map into a form in an Access database. I am trying to find out the number of tables loaded but NumTables() and MapperInfo() are both getting "unrecognized command" errors.

Is there another way to get the number of tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use Mapinfo.Eval and MapInfo.Do and wrap the other requests.  You can't simply call MapBasic functions in Integrated mapping, you need to do them through these two methods, if I remember correctly.

So, something like this:

```
If mapinfo.Eval("TableInfo(" & tabName & "," & 5 & ")") = "F" Then
    MsgBox "Cannot open table!"

mapinfo.Do "Close Table " & tabName
```

So use eval when extracting info:

```
MsgBox("Num tables : " + str$(Mapinfo.Eval(NumTables())))
```

Or something like that.

And MapInfo.Do for executing a command:

```
Mapinfo.Do "Close Table " & tabName
```

Also, you can run menu commands in integrated mapping thus:

```
"zoomin":
Mapinfo.runmenucommand 1705

"zoomout":
Mapinfo.runmenucommand 1706

"info":
Mapinfo.runmenucommand 1707

"layerctrl":
Mapinfo.runmenucommand 801

"select":
Mapinfo.runmenucommand 1701

"deselect":
Mapinfo.runmenucommand 304

"label":
Mapinfo.runmenucommand 1708

"grabber":
Mapinfo.runmenucommand 1702

"open":
Mapinfo.runmenucommand 102

"save":
Mapinfo.runmenucommand 109
```

Again, untested code and from the memory banks of many years ago when I worked there on MapBasic projects.